# django-test-utils global name 'setup_test_environment' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm trying to use django-test-utils to keep my database after test running.

But when I execute quicktest command:

```
python manage.py quicktest
```

I obtain this error:

```
re/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/apps/desarrollo/workspace/3sure-server/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/apps/desarrollo/workspace/3sure-server/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/apps/desarrollo/workspace/3sure-server/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_utils/management/commands/quicktest.py", line 30, in handle
    failures = test_runner(test_labels, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive)
  File "/apps/desarrollo/workspace/3sure-server/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_utils/test_runners/keep_database.py", line 30, in run_tests
    setup_test_environment()
NameError: global name 'setup_test_environment' is not defined
```

I've installed django-test-utils using pip and referenced the application in my settings.py. Did I miss an installation step?

I'm using Django==1.4.3 and django-test-utils==0.3

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is extremely old. It's last specified support is Django 1.2. By looking at the error message and where `setup_test_environment` is called, I'm assuming the `pip` version is even older.

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ericholscher/django-test-utils) on Github, you'll see that the file `keep_database.py` has been updated to import `setup_test_environment` specifically:

`from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment`

This is not in the older versions of the code, which are probably the versions that you `pip` installed - thus the error.

Again, this project as a whole is old and you should find an alternative, but if you must use this project I suggest you get a fresh fork from the Github link above and manually install via `setup.py`.